# Charan: A Place or Avraham's Brother (Or Both)?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment

Is there any significance to the fact that the city Charan is closely related to the name of Avraham's brother, Haran?

Comment: The brother's name was הרן not חרן. Different spelling.

Comment: That makes sense, my question came from reading the Thomas Mann novel "Joseph and His Brothers" where he kind of implies that Charan being the name of a city and Avraham's brother reflects an inaccuracy in the Torah. But now I realize his mistake.

Comment: Even if they had the same spelling, that wouldn't be any kind of "inaccuracy." In the Torah there are lots of examples of people having the same names as cities, starting with Chanoch ben Kayin. Nowadays, too, you can have Florence from Florence, Austin from Austin, etc., and in a book of Hebrew names from decades ago I saw names such as Yerushalayim, Tel Aviv and Chevron (the last already a Biblical name).

Comment: @Meir, don't forget יאיר and שכם